# "No Photos" in OSX with PTP?

Tags: usb, photos

I delayed trying to fix this for a few years but now I'm having enough of it: photos on my Android phones do not show up in Image Capture/Lightroom/Photos.app on my OS X machines.

- File transfer (MTP) mode works just fine. I can see the DCIM folder, the photos in it, and there is no .NOMEDIA file that I can find.
- PTP sort of works I guess? The apps recognize the phone, but do not display any of the files.
- Tried power cycling the phones, but no go.
- Tried connection the cable at different stages, with the phone locked/unlocked, still no go.
- Problem started with Yosemite/El Capitan/Sierra -- I don't quite remember which but a long while ago.

Anyone ever encountered this?

Comment: I have the exact same situation. Photos.app opens when I connect the phone but it says there are no photos on the phone.